# I want to use input::checked with :has but it doesn't work

Tags: html, css

as you can see in my code i want to unhide span when input type checked is checked, but it doesnt work. Could you please help me?

```css
.share_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0.7rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-inline: 10px;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
}

.share_div label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: black;
  margin-inline-start: 2rem;
  margin-block-start: 0.5rem;
}

#actuall_link {
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);
  height: 2.2rem;
}

#share_div:has(>input::checked) span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="share_div" class="share_div">
  <label for="checkbox_share">info</label>
  <input id="checkbox_share" type="checkbox">
  <span id="actuall_link">unhide when checkbox is checked</span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's `:checked`, not `::checked`. You're confusing pseduoelements with pseudoclasses.

Comment: ...and for the love of everyone's eyesight **indent your code**.

Comment: Also, you don't even need `:has()` in this case because the checkbox `<input>` is a preceding sibling of the `<span>`, so you only need `#share_div > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span { }`

Comment: `actuall_link` ? you mean `actual_link`

Comment: FYI:  instead of using ID and FOR attributes, simply wrap your INPUT and SPAN inside the LABEL, and remove those silly, verbose attributes.

Comment: @Dai initial is equal to inline when applied to display. initial doesn't consider the element, it's a defined value based on the property. Each property has one initial value

Comment: @TemaniAfif Really? dang, that's disappointing

Comment: @Dai what you are describing is `revert`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert .. read the second note in that link to see difference with initial

Comment: @TemaniAfif That's what I'm after, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's `:checked`, not `::checked`. You're confusing pseduoelements with pseudoclasses.

Also, you don't even need `:has()` in this case because the checkbox `<input>` is a preceding sibling of the `<span>`, so you only need `#share_div > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span { }`

---

### Solution 1: Using `~` (without `:has()`):

```css
.share_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0.7rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-inline: 10px;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
}

.share_div label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: black;
  margin-inline-start: 2rem;
  margin-block-start: 0.5rem;
}

#actuall_link {
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);
  height: 2.2rem;
}

#share_div > input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ span {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="share_div" class="share_div">
  <label for="checkbox_share">info</label>
  <input id="checkbox_share" type="checkbox">
  <span id="actuall_link">unhide when checkbox is checked</span>
</div>
```

### Solution 2: Using `:has()`:

...[with `display: revert;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert).

```css
.share_div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0.7rem;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #aaa;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding-inline: 10px;
  border-radius: 100vmax;
}

.share_div label {
  display: block;
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  color: black;
  margin-inline-start: 2rem;
  margin-block-start: 0.5rem;
}

#actuall_link {
  display: none;
  width: calc(100% - 5rem);
  height: 2.2rem;
}

#share_div:has( > input[type=checkbox]:checked ) > span {
  display: revert;
}
```

```html
<div id="share_div" class="share_div">
  <label for="checkbox_share">info</label>
  <input id="checkbox_share" type="checkbox">
  <span id="actuall_link">unhide when checkbox is checked</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

- Remove the overly verbose attributes `id` and `for`.
- Wrap your elements into `label`
- Use the [Adjacent sibling combinator `+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) (or the [General sibling combinator `~`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator) if not an immediate next sibling)
- As already mentioned, it should be `:checked`, not a *pseudo-element* `::checked`

```css
label                 .msg { display: none;    }
label input:checked + .msg { display: initial; }
```

```html
<label>
  info
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="msg">Good job!</span>
</label>
```